# Different way to provide static resources with ResourceHandlerRegistry

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have to startup a Angular 1 application with Java backend. I thought to use the same folder structure of a previous one done months before with Angular 1 as frontend and Storngloop as backend.

My frontend web application is composed by this folder structure:

```
src
  |
  main
    |
    webapp
        |
        client
```

Inside app folder ich habe the whole application composed by subfolders which inside other .css, .js, .html files (in every folder ther's a part of my application. By instance: login form folder, with its `.css`, `.html` and `.js` files inside and so on...).

Something like:

```
client
      |
      login
          |
          login.html
          |
          login.css
          |
          login.js
      stuff
          |
          stuff.html
          |
          stuff.css
          |
          stuff.js
```

and in the index.html I would do `(2)`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="client/login/login.css">
...
<script src="client/login/login.js"></script>
```

So I thought to configure my `ResourceHandlerRegistry` as follows `(1)`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package")
public class Configurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/client/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //resources locations
        registry.addResourceHandler("client/**").addResourceLocations("/client/**");
    }

}
```

but when in my `index.html` file I try to include any of `.js` or `.css` files I got 404 from the server for each resource included in point `(2)`... as I expected... I had to do this `(3)`:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("client/**").addResourceLocations("/client/", "/client/login/", "/client/stuff/", //ecc... ecc...);
```

declaring every single path to every resource of my frontend verithing works perfectly! Really, I know that's ugly!

Can be done something like the `(1)` without declaring EVERY SINGLE RESOURCE PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1. **Config :**

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/client/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/client/");
}
```

2. **Jsps :**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/client/login/login.css" />">
<script src="<c:url value="/client/login/login.js" />"></script>
```